# What is the option that makes Sublime Text add whitespace at the left of wrapped lines?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

I want Sublime to treat my text files like they are source code files and show whitespace at the left of wrapped lines, like so:

```
beginning of long line blah blah blah, now it wraps
    and it keeps going after an automatic indent
```

I tried opening the console and setting the option manually:

```
view.settings().set('indent_subsequent_lines', True)
```

but nothing changes, any ideas?

Comment: http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, that was fun. There's no easily accessible setting for this. But as you indicate, ST decides whether to add an extra indent when soft wrapping, from whether the syntax is considered code-like or plain text-like.

Being one or the other is up to the package defining the syntax to specify. So lacking a global setting from ST, you need to change your text packages. As an example, let's take `Text`. That contains `Plain text.tmLanguage`. In that you change

```
<key>scopeName</key>
<string>text.plain</string>
```

to

```
<key>scopeName</key>
<string>source.plain</string>
```

I'm unsure of whether there'll be ill effects from not keeping `.plain`.

One easy way to do this is to get the `PackageResourceViewer`package.

After install, do:

- <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>
- Type: `Open Resource`
- <kbd>return</kbd>
- Type: `Text`
- <kbd>return</kbd>
- Type: `Plain text.tmLanguage`
- Make your edit and save.

`PackageResourceViewer` will save the modified `Text` package to your Packages directory. And sublime will display files considered to have `Plain text`-syntax, like they are code.

The caveat is that you need to do this for every text-syntax you want to be considered code.

Comment: Note that many languages are now using a `.sublime-syntax` file (which is a YAML file) instead of, or in addition to, a `.tmLanguage` file (which are XML .plists).  So you may need to change it in those, too.  In YAML the correct one to edit is just the first `scope:` line, where the main scope name of the language is identified (there will be lots of other `scope:` entries further down under `contexts:`).  Trying to get "PlainTasks" to indent on wrap, I edited in several different places, but it was in the `.sublime-syntax` that finally got it to take.

Comment: This breaks spell check. Is there any way to repair that?

Answer (score 1):

As @AdamAL said, it's dependent on both the `'indent_subsequent_lines'` setting as well as whether it's considered a "source" or a "text" language ... by default, "markup" languages (such as HTML, CSS, etc.) and plain text, etc., are considered "text", and programming languages such as C++, Java, PHP, etc., are considered "source".

"Source" languages will indent subsequent soft-wrapped lines (if the `indent_subsequent_lines` is `true`), whereas "text" languages will only indent up to the same level as the current line.

For each one you want to change, you'll need to edit the settings of the given language.  [@AdamAL's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21562924/1593026)  provides a great way to do this using the `PackageResourceViewer` package:

> After install, do:
>
> [Ctrl/Cmd]+[shift]+p, `"Open Resource"`

Find the name of the language you want to change, and find either the `.sublime-syntax` file or the `.tmLanguage` file.  [`.sublime-syntax` is supported from build 3084 of ST 3](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/syntaxdefs.html?highlight=scopename) and appears that it may trump values in the `.tmLanguage` file in supported versions, if present (when editing the definition of TaskPaper files provided by the "PlainTasks" package, my change didn't take when just editing the `PlainTasks.tmLanguage`, I had to edit the `PlainTasks.sublime-syntax` before it took).

In `.sublime-syntax` (which are YAML files) look for the first `scope:` line, where the main scope name of the language is identified (there will be lots of other `scope:` entries further down under `contexts:`).

In `.tmLanguage` (which are XML .plist files) look for the `<string>` following the `<key>scopeName</key>`.

[Sublime Text Syntax Definition Documentation Reference](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/syntaxdefs.html?highlight=scopename):

> **scopeName**
>
> Name of the topmost scope for this syntax definition. Either `source.<lang>` or `text.<lang>`. Use source for programming languages and text for markup and everything else.

The `<lang>` (without brackets) is just an identifier string for the given syntax/language definition.

I noted that it seems that (in ST 3, anyway), no restart of Sublime Text is needed to get the changes to apply, if the edit is in the right place.

And also note that there may be other effects of changing this in more complex packages -- For example, in PlainTasks, the additional keybindings that it defines depended on it looking for a `context` that included `text.todo`, which I changed to `source.todo` in several places.  So in order for the keybindings to work properly again, I also had to update my `.sublime-keymap` for that package.  (This could also be because I changed it in a place besides the `.sublime-syntax` that I didn't need to. Just sayin' -- YMMV.)